# onPress not working in Victory chart in React Native while running in android

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

React Native Victory charts : onPress or onPressIn is not triggered in android. however it is OK in iOS.

Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: <VictoryPie
        colorScale={["green", "red", "blue" ]}
        events={ [{
          target: 'data',
          eventHandlers: {
            onPress: (evt, context, index) => {
             alert(index);
            },
          },
        }] }
        data={[
          { x: 1, y: 60, label: "A" },
          { x: 2, y: 30, label: "B" },
          { x: 3, y: 10, label: "C" }
        ]}
/>

Answer (score 0):

I found out (by reading other stackoverflow issues addressing similar problems) that wrapping the whole VictoryChart in an `<Svg>...</Svg>` solves this issue on Android and on the other hand keeps the onPress functionality on iOS. The only thing I realized on top was that I had to give the Svg a `style={{height: XXX}}` where XXX is the same height than the VictoryChart has. Otherwise the wrapping Svg would be gigantic high.